# PHP rewrite data text in mysql but not unique column

Tags: php, mysql, unique

I have a problem with rewrite data in mysql.

User has a **checkbox** "Rewrite data" and **textarea** where 1 line is 1 data.

Example form:

[x] Rewrite

textarea:

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
data8
data15
```

I have a mysql table with name "data" and its columns *id INT, user_id INT, data (TEXT)*

My database right now:

```
id, user_id, data
1    56     data3
1    56     data8
1    56     data2
```

etc..

If user check the checkbox and submit form, i need to add **data1,data2,data4,data15** to database and **data2,3,8 should be ignore**.
But **if user does not check** the checkbox - i need to add **data1,2,3,4,8,15** and mysql table should be like this:

```
1    56     data3
1    56     data8
1    56     data2
1    56     data1
1    56     data2
1    56     data3
1    56     data4
1    56     data8
1    56     data15
```

I have just one idea, first - select all data of this user to array and foreach it, but if user has 100k data in table it will be bad.

Comment: If you don't want to put 100k data rows in a loop... you will execute 100k SQL queries or ? I'm so confused now I don't know... something is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this could work.

Dummy code:

```
if rewrite is checked
    fetch existing duplicate data (check query below)

loop new data lines
    if rewrite is checked and current line exists in duplicates array
        continue
    else
        insert new data
```

Example query for duplicates array:

```
SELECT data_table.data
FROM data data_table
WHERE data_table.user_id = $userId
AND data_table.data IN($listWithNewData)
```